# How to extract binary executables on native lib folder on Android

Tags: android

I need to execute binaries on Android Q, so...

In which folder on Android Studio do I have to put my executables in order to send them to the native lib folder (As this seems to be the only solution)?

I tried to put them in several places with no success:

- app/lib
- app/libs
- app/lib/{ABI}
- app/libs/{ABI}
- app/src/main/resources/lib/{ABI}
- app/src/main/resources/libs/{ABI}

And none of them worked.

I also renamed the files to the standard lib_*.so, and I expected them to be moved to the directory `context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir`

I also setted `android:extractNativeLibs="true"` to the application tag on manifest and setted the `android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs = false` on gradle.properties.

With this code I try to execute the file:

```
static ProcessBuilder loadDefault(Context context)
{
  try
  {
    String dir = context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir;

    String fileName;
    String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");

    if (arch != null && arch.contains("aarch64") && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
      fileName = "lib_my_executable_for_arm64.so";
    }
    else
    {
      fileName = "lib_my_executable_for_armeabi.so";
    }

    String path = dir + "/" + fileName;
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);

    try
    {
      process.waitFor();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ignore)
    {}

    return new ProcessBuilder(path);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I always get the error `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/app/com.mypackage.myapp-1jm1HSWBtoM6ih1AoXUZ5A==/lib/arm64/lib_my_executable_for_arm64.so": error=2, No such file or directory`.

Please, I need help! I don't know what else to do. =/

Comment: make sure your binaries are built for these architectures, just saying becuase I was stuck with the same issue for days until I realised my binaries were wrong. Also not sure if it is the only way but I do create a symlink before I try to execute them Os.symlink(dir+filename, context.filesDir+newfilename)